# memory is of VS. memory is

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

> My earliest memory is being shown around my house
>
> My earliest memory is of being shown around my house.

Is there any difference between these?

***UPDATED:***
And, what is your opinion about this rephrasing?

My earliest memory of being shown around my house is.

I am really confused when to use ***of***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence, with "is of", is correct and unambiguous.

The first sentence, *My earliest memory is being shown around my house*, is ambiguous. When I read the sentence, I was trying to understand how a memory could be "shown around my house". Perhaps a related photo is on the wall, or a memento is displayed that is somehow linked to "my earliest memory". When I read the second sentence, the meaning was clear.

In conversation, I would probably understand the meaning of the first sentence. But in written communication, the first sentence initially confused me. The second sentence is correct and unambiguous in both written and oral communication.

From the updated question (*My earliest memory of being shown around my house is*):

When a sentence ends in *is*, the sentence is often a statement about the existence of the subject. As written, the sentence means, *My earliest memory of being shown around my house exists*.

This sentence sounds awkward to a native speaker. Most listeners or readers would think, "Your earliest memory is ... *what*?". In most contexts, something comes after *is*. I would strongly discourage using this sentence.

Comment: Thanks. But my specific problem is about "of".

Comment: I am wondering how to understand it here

Comment: [This page](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx) says _of_ is used for belonging to, relating to, or connected with. For example, _I dreamed of being rich and famous_ is similar to your sentence _My earliest memory is of being shown around my house_.

Comment: @nima_persian.  We had another question that involved the word "of" recently.  A thorough dictionary would have to devote many pages to all of the ways the preposition can be used. Do not take as the final word what you read in a pocket or online dictionary. The main requirements of such dictionaries are that they be brief and accurate, not that they be thorough and painstaking in the way they separate the possible usages.

Comment: See OED **of** VIII. 26.

Answer (score 3):

American English native-speaker gut check: they are both acceptable and either would be understood correctly with no ambiguity, but the second, "is of", sounds more correct to me.  It seems to me that one can have a memory of being shown around a house, but being shown around a house is not, itself, a memory.  I suppose, it is like pictures: one can say "the first picture I took *is* the front of the house" and that will be understood, but it's not as precise as saying "the first picture I took *is of* the front of the house".

But I am totally open to the possibility that I'm being wrong here, or at least pedantic in a particularly computer programmerish way.  ["Ceci n'est pas une pipe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images); the pointer is not the value; pass by value is vs. pass by reference; etc.

Comment: This is my last question: I think you would rather use is of rather than other things like is about etc.,?

Comment: @nima_persian, yes, "is of" is better than "about" when describing the contents of memories.